# how to avoid a python script to hangs until both user uses ctrl+C & keep it possible

Tags: python, algorithm, exit

Was given a script I would reuse more or less, I need to be able to to both :

- end the execution by itself
- capture ctrl-c to exit on user action

I saw many clues to the second part on other answers/question of stackoverflow similar to :

```
try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
    pass
```

In my point of view I should run the execution functions (main) in

```
while mycondition:
    try:
        mainfunction()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        personalised_exit()
```

Why not (*if I undersoud well as I am still a python noob*), but why not a more declarative code with usage of signal modules ?
something might look then like

```
import signal
import sys

def signal_handler(sig, frame):
    [...]
    sys.exit(0)

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
main()
signal.pause()
```

Comment: You _can_ implement your own signal handler if you want to. Do you have a specific technical problem here or are you just asking why a specific idiom is frequently recommended? (I'm not sure the latter question is on-topic at all; a question needs to be narrow, specific, and amendable to a canonical / provably-correct answer rather than a matter of opinion; why people recommend one thing and not another when both work equally well is pretty far into matters of opinion).

Comment: Ok so it is more or less a choice of method then ? so I can use any of those examples to make them fit my needs ?

Comment: Pretty much. If you hit a problem whereby you _can't_ use either approach, and it's not covered in our knowledge base, come back and ask about that problem -- something that doesn't work is more clearly inside our rules than a place where you're deciding between two separate approaches that are both reasonable on their face.